# Pug Templates - How to mark option in Dropdown list as selected

Tags: pug

I have a Pug template that uses Bootstrap 4 as the 'layout' and receiving data from an Express/Mongoose server.

I am populating a form from MongoDB so the contents can be edited.  I have been looking for ways to make a dropdown-list 'select' an option based on the value from the mongoDB document.

I have seen ways of building the dropdown-list from scratch and setting an option as 'selected', but the form is already generated and has a dropdown-list already in place.  I just need to match the option with the value from the mongoDB document and set the option to display in the list.

The Pug template is as follows:

```
.row
  .col-sm-6
    .form-group
      label.control-label.requiredField(for='propertyType')
        | Property Type
        span.asteriskField *
      .col-xs-12
        select#propertyType.select.form-control.input-lg(form='addProperty', name='propertyType')
          option(value='0') -- Select --
          option(value='6') Home
          option(value='7') Condo
          option(value='10') Single Family Home
          option(value='11') Town House
          option(value='12') City Apartment
          option(value='13') Villa


script.
  var propertyType = document.getElementById('propertyType');

  for (var i = 0; i < propertyType.options.length; i++) {

    if (propertyType.options[i].value = #{property.typeId}) {
        propertyType.options[i].selected = 'selected';
        propertyType.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }

  }
```

If I keep the code as listed then the actual option that gets a new value is the first one '-- Select --' which has it's value changed from '0' to '6', which is the value from the MongoDB document.

If I change the javascript to pass the value #{property.TypeId} to the 'selectedIndex' like this:

```
propertyType.selectedIndex = #{property.typeId};
```

Then the value of the index changes and the 'selected' option changes - to '6' but this then selects the 6th option of the options and not the one with the value of '6'.

Drop-downs are the only thing I can't seem to populate so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Hope it's ok to answer my own question.  I did try Mohit's approach, but it didn't work for me.

I added a 'script.' section under each `<select>` input:

```
script.
  var pOptions = document.getElementById('propertyType').options;
  for (i=0; i < pOptions.length; i++) {
    if (pOptions[i].value == #{property.typeId}) pOptions[i].selected = true;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine to answer your own question. This is a Q&A site, and every Q deserves an A!

Answer (score 25):

If you just need to show an option pre-selected, then I don't think you need to use javascript for this. You can try this:

```
.row
  .col-sm-6
    .form-group
      label.control-label.requiredField(for='propertyType')
        | Property Type
        span.asteriskField *
      .col-xs-12
        select#propertyType.select.form-control.input-lg(form='addProperty', name='propertyType')
          option(value='0', selected= true) -- Select --
          option(value='6', selected= property.id == 6) Home
          option(value='7', selected= property.id == 7) Condo
          option(value='10', selected= property.id == 10) Single Family Home
          option(value='11', selected= property.id == 11) Town House
          option(value='12', selected= property.id == 12) City Apartment
          option(value='13', selected= property.id == 13) Villa
```

Assuming this dropdown shows the values corresponding to `property.id`, it will mark the `selected` attribute as true for the `option` whose value matches the value in `property.id`. Otherwise, first option will be shown selected by default.

Comment: But if you have 30 options (lots I know), you would have to write a lot of code.  Seems it would increase updating your code base.

Comment: @Pandafinity Yes it would require a lot of code to be updated. But you can use a loop to iterate through different options and put the selected condition inside that loop. Provided that is feasible in your case.

Comment: I'm sorry Mohit but I see this as an inefficient solution.  Especially if you then have other workflows that use different identifiers to make something applicable to be 'selected'.  Say if you have a dynamic dataset that have groups that use different selectors to define the default value?  You would have to add more code to define between those selectors...  Thanks though.

Comment: @Pandafinity :( not sure why didn't work for you, but I use it. logic is simple, that if `selected` attribute is assigned `true` value in jade, it reflects in html as `selected="selected"` and that option is shown as selected. So, here one of our expressions would result true or by default the first would be shown as selected.

Comment: I'll give it another go ;)

Comment: I found this was giving me 'selected=""' on the one entry that had a matching ID, and no selected tag on any of the others. This didn't work because an empty string is falsey.

Comment: @kiml42 it depends on how you define the condition. In the example in this answer, the condition ` property.id == 6` should return true or false, so no string is expected. How are you specifying your condition?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I think I was actually getting something else wrong. It's still giving me 'selected=""' but it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use modified version

```
select#content-display.form-control(name='grid_entry_source_type')
  each elem in [{'name': 'All', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'Pick up', 'value': 2}]
    option(value=elem.value, selected=(elem.value === result.grid_entry_source_type))= elem.name
```

Answer (score 12):

I used [Mohit Bhardwaj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40014057/90674) in a for loop for a simple solution.

```
select(name='image')
  option(value='' selected=!project.image) (empty)
  for img in images
    option(value=img.id selected=(img.id === project.image.id)) #{img.alt}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation [here](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#boolean-attributes) I've found a solution that requires no javascript and works inline.

This is how I've used it in my code:

```
select(name="priority")
    each priority in priorities
        option(value=priority.id selected=(job.priority.id == priority.id) ) #{priority.name}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution it pointed me to my solution where I have a variable in template do I did simply 'option(value="xy" selected=(xy==variable)) xy' and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this without requiring a script tag or unfurling the loop at all.

```
-var selected = true;
select(id=field.id required=required)
    each op in field.options
        option(value=op name=field.name selected=selected) #{op}
        -if(selected){
            -selected=false;
        -}
```

This will set the very first option in the list to "selected" utilizing the attribute setting syntax (if `selected` is true when evaluated `selected=selected`, it will append the tag).

Answer (score 0):

```
              here is index.pug
              /////////////////////   

           extends layout


           block content
           h1= title
           //- p Welcome to #{title}
         style.
         input[type=text], select {
         width: 20%;
         padding: 12px 20px;
         margin: 8px 0;
         display: inline-block;
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         border-radius: 4px;
         box-sizing: border-box;
          }
       input[type=submit] {
       width: 10%;
       background-color: #4CAF50;
       color: white;
       padding: 14px 20px;
       margin: 8px 0;
       border: none;
       border-radius: 4px;
       cursor: pointer;
        }
       input[type=submit]:hover {
       background-color: #45a049;
       }
     div {
      border-radius: 1px;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 20px; }
     link(rel='stylesheet', href='/scripts/css/bootstrap.css')
     script(src="/scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js")
     //-      //- 

       script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js")
       script(src="/jquery/jquery.js")
       h3 Choose Your Skill
       - var  optos = skills
 div
    form(action='/Skill' method="post")
 div
    label Enter- 
    input(type='text',id='zaftot',name="zaftot" ,onKeyup="myFunc(this.value)"         
    autofocus="autofocus") 
    input(type='submit',  value='Submit')  
 div   

    select(name='dropdown' id="myselect" size="4" ,onClick="myclick()",style="margin- 
    left:40px" )


    script.
          function myclick(){ 
          var t=$("#myselect").val().toString();
          $("#zaftot").val(t);
          $("#zaftot").focus();
          $("#myselect").hide();
        /// alert(t);
         };
     function memo(){ 
       /// remove  all items of list
        var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
        while(true){ 
        if (x.length > 0) {
          x.remove(x.length-1);
               }
               else{
                 break;
               }
             }
          }

     function myFunc(inp){
        $("#myselect").show();

          memo(); //clear list before initiatig new one
       if (inp.length >0){
        //alert(inp +'----hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh');
        var aa =!{JSON.stringify(optos)}
        var uu =inp.trim().toLowerCase();
         for (i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
          var  tt =aa[i].trim().toLowerCase();
          //var y =tt.substr(0,uu.length);
          //alert(uu);
          //if(tt.substr(0,uu.length))===uu {  // substr() not working i dont know
            if(tt.indexOf(uu)>-1){ 
              $('#myselect').append('<option>' + aa[i] + '</option>');
            };
         };
     };
    };
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

          here is  routes /index.js  
          /////////////////////////////

        /*esversion=6 */
        var express = require('express');
        var router = express.Router();

       router.get("/", function (req, res) {
        var  skills =["MVC", "C#", "mmm","mlll","moo","muuu" 
        ,"mdd","mkkkk","Node  
        JS", 
       "mkyy" ,  "Python" ,  "IDE visual studio","Mssql"];
        res.render('index', {
          title : "Select technology",
         skills:skills
        });
       });

     router.post("/Skill" , function(req, res){
     console.log(req.body);
     res.render('Skill',{
     skill: req.body.dropdown
     });
     });

    module.exports = router;
        //////////////////////////////////////
           package json
          {
         "name": "aziz",
            "version": "0.0.0",
            "private": true,
          "scripts": {
           "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
         },
         "dependencies": {
         "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
         "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
         "debug": "~2.6.9",
        "eslint": "^5.5.0",
         "express": "~4.16.0",
         "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "morgan": "~1.9.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
         "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
         "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
        },
      "author": "azizsallam",
       "license": "ISC"
        }     
        ///////////////////////////
         add these two line to app.js

 ////////////ADD TO APP.JS the next line how to call bootstrap files in yuor          
            ///////////////////  the next line how to call bootstrap files 
 in yuor view ///////////////////
 app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + 
 '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/'));
 app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + 
 '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));
   //////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: WORKING EXAMPLE  WITH NODE and  EXPRESS and pug template engine modified  from  another post on stack over flow  that --POSTED 19TH MAY 2018 CHEN V http://chen.about-powershell.com/2018/05/dynamically-populate-data-for-drop-down-list-using-pug-in-node-js/

Comment: This is very broad

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Comment: use express generator to  build your  app folder and initiate json package ,

Comment: MR Saeed   ---I JUST ADDED  PACKAGE.JSON  too